# django-haystack unable to order by score

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am using Haystack (2.4.1) with Whoosh (2.6.0) backend.

I *am able* to sort my SearchQuerySet by my personally defined field, `modified`, but **not** Haystack's build-in `score`. I couldn't find anything about this in Haystack's documentation, but I did found an example online that seemed to indicate that the `.order_by('-score', '-modified')` below should work:

```
        sqs = (SearchQuerySet()
               .models(MyModel)
               .order_by('-score', '-modified'))
```

but it doesn't; instead, I get a GET 500 error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the stack trace for the log generated when you get a 500 error.

Comment: The only message that gets appended to the log when I search is the 500 error itself: `[06/Sep/2016 09:35:04] "GET /api/v3/object/search/?page=1&q=banana+apple HTTP/1.1" 500 3072`.